# he sandboxed code execution request was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a event receiver in my project and in the event receiver I have following code. It is bound to  custom list.

public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdding(properties);

// Get the web where the event was raised

```
       SPWeb spCurrentSite = properties.OpenWeb();

       //Get the name of the list where the event was raised         

       String curListName = properties.ListTitle;

       //If the list is our list named SubSites the create a new subsite directly below the current site

       if (curListName == "Customers")
       {

           //Get the SPListItem object that raised the event

           SPListItem curItem = properties.ListItem;

           //Get the Title field from this item. This will be the name of our new subsite
           String curItemSiteName = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();

           //Get the Description field from this item. This will be the description for our new subsite

           string curItemDescription = properties.AfterProperties["Description"].ToString();

           //Update the SiteUrl field of the item, this is the URL of our new subsite

           properties.AfterProperties["SiteUrl"] = spCurrentSite.Url + "/" + curItemSiteName;

           //Create the subsite based on the template from the Solution Gallery

           SPWeb newSite = spCurrentSite.Webs.Add(curItemSiteName, curItemSiteName, curItemDescription, Convert.ToUInt16(1033), "WIKI#0", false, false);

           //Set the new subsite to inherit it's top navigation from the parent site, Usefalse if you do not want this.
           newSite.Navigation.UseShared = true;
           CreateList(newSite);
           newSite.Close();

       }

   }
```

This code works fine for farm solutions. For sandbox solutions it gives exception at :
  SPWeb newSite = spCurrentSite.Webs.Add(curItemSiteName, curItemSiteName, curItemDescription, Convert.ToUInt16(1033), "WIKI#0", false, false);

Says "he sandboxed code execution request was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request."

Any suggestion??

Comment: Sandboxed solutions were deprecated. Don't use them. Heavy lifting such as creating site in an ItemAdding event handler seem overkill to me.

Comment: What I need was, need to deploy solution to Office 365. I hope only Sandboxed solutions support for SharePoint online.

Comment: Use Apps for SharePoint. Sandboxed solutions are problematic.